# Divide Hamiltonian Cycle Optimally

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

My friend gave this to me as a brain teaser but I'm at quite a loss as to how to approach this without brute force.

Let's say we're given a Hamiltonian Cycle that starts and ends at p0 after going through m other vertices v1 through vm. But now we want to divide this cycle into two largely disjoint cycles. Both cycles start and end at p0, but v1 through vm are partitioned between the two cycles so as to minimize the distance traveled collectively. The only condition is that if i < j, then vi < vj must hold true in any given cycle. The distance function between any two vertices is arbitrary and Distance(i,j) = Distance(j,i).

I know this is possible if we check all potential partitions of vertices among the two cycles. But that seems slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem using dynamic programming in `O(m^2)` time (maybe you even faster? I didn't try to improve on it). The idea is that for each `i` and `j` with `i < j`, you compute the optimal way `W[i][j]` to construct one path to `v[i]` and another disjoint path to `v[j]`, where the two paths use up all of the vertices from `v[1]` to `v[j]`. These can be computed efficiently just by looking at the possibilities for the second-to-last vertex in the path ending at `v[j]`.

At the end, you consider `W[i][m]` for each `i`, and you see what you get by closing off both paths by going back to `p[0]`. Then you pick the best one.

Comment: Would this take care of making sure that all vertices v1 through vm were used?

Comment: Yes, I edited to make it a bit clearer. The `W[i][j]` should consider pairs of paths where all vertices up to `v[j]` are used.